# Shaded relief / Hill shade - GRASS vs GDAL and QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, grass-gis, hillshade, shaded-relief

I tried generating shaded relief / hill shade maps using different algorithms in GRASS and QGIS. It was found that r.relief of GRASS produced more realistic terrain shading compared to GDAL Hillshade and native Hillshade algorithm of QGIS. This happens regardless of using same azimuth and altitude parameters. Shaded relief maps from ERDAS Imagine is also similar to that from r.relief. Can anybody explain why this happens? Is there any difference between Hill shade and shaded relief?

Comment: Shaded relief and hill shade creates the 3D nature of the terrain by showing the shadow created by a light source. So, I think they are both same. Could you share the three images generated by the three algorithms?

Comment: Could you also add the exact parameters that you used with gdaldem https://gdal.org/programs/gdaldem.html?